# Proximity sensor method android

Tags: android

I was unable to implement a method while using proximity sensor.I wanted to use the value of proximity sensor such that to perform a task when the event value of sensor remains same for a particular interval of time.Can we use timer for that ?

Comment: i have tried to implement timer but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but will a `onSensorChanged()`-Event be raised? If so, compare the time from last event here and if it is in your interval call your method, else update time from last event to current event.